# problems with program to compare input values to const array of values

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to write a program that will take an array of correct answers

```
const char correctAnswers[] = {'B','D', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D'};
```

compare that to a user input of they answers...

```
char studentAnswers[] = {};
```

and then find out how many of the answers they got correct, but I find myself running into errors trying to compare the two arrays

```
bool grade(char correctAnswers, char studentAnswers){
    
    for(int b=0; b<10; b++){
            for(int j=0; j<10; j++){
                if(correctAnswers[b]==studentAnswers[j]){ //HERE
                    ++ansCorrect;
                }
            }
                
        }

    
    if(ansCorrect >= 8){  //8 out of 10 correct
        return true;}
    else;
        return false;
}
```

now I don't agree with some of the methods I had to use to make this function but it is required that I have the program return true or false for if they passed. I've been tweaking with it for a bit and my whole program only shows and error on the line where is says //HERE there error message is (Subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector)

here is my full code if that would help, be warned it is very messy and there are definitely some unnecessary variables and global variables.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool grade();
int ansCorrect = 0;
const char correctAnswers[] = {'B','D', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D'};
char studentAnswers[] = {};

int main ()
{
    
    int i = 0;
    int questionNum = 1;
    int chances = 0;
    char response;
    
//Ask for student answer and checks if the input is valid
do {
        cout << "What was the answer to Question "<< questionNum<< ": \n";
        cin >> response;
        
  
          switch (response){
            case 'A':
                  studentAnswers[i] = response;
                  questionNum++;
                      i++;
                  break;
            case 'a':
                  studentAnswers[i] = response;
                  questionNum++;
                      i++;
                  break;
            case 'B':
                  studentAnswers[i] = response;
                  questionNum++;
                      i++;
                  break;
            case 'b':
                  studentAnswers[i] = response;
                  questionNum++;
                      i++;
                  break;
            case 'C':
                  studentAnswers[i] = response;
                  questionNum++;
                      i++;
                  break;
            case 'c':
                  studentAnswers[i] = response;
                  questionNum++;
                      i++;
                  break;
            case 'D':
                  studentAnswers[i] = response;
                  questionNum++;
                      i++;
                  break;
            case 'd':
                  studentAnswers[i] = response;
                  questionNum++;
                      i++;
                  break;
           default:
              cout << "Please enter a valid input (A, B, C, D)\n";
              chances++;
              if (chances == 3){
                  cout << "GOODBYE";
                  break;    }
          }
    } while (i < 10);

        
        

        
    
    
    bool result = grade();
    if (result==true){
        cout << "Congratulations!\nYou have passed exam.";
    if (result==false)
        cout << "Sorry, you have not passed the exam!";
}
    cout << "total number of correct answers: "<< ansCorrect;
    cout << "total number of incorrect answers: "<< 10 - ansCorrect;
    
    
return 0;
}

bool grade(char correctAnswers, char studentAnswers){
    
    for(int b=0; b<10; b++){
            for(int j=0; j<10; j++){
                if(correctAnswers[b]==studentAnswers[j]){
                    ++ansCorrect;
                }
            }
                
        }

    
    if(ansCorrect >= 8){//8 out of 10 correct
        return true;}
    else;
        return false;
}
```

I would also like to add that some of the methods I used might not be idle so if you have any opinions on easier methods that would help alot!

Comment: `char studentAnswers[] = {};` How big do you think that array is?

Comment: See also:  `std::toupper()` and `std::tolower`.  It will reduce your `switch` statement by half.

Comment: The arguments to `grade` are single characters, not arrays.  It's unclear why you're attempting to perform a O(N^2) comparison between the two answer arrays.  You're doing 100 comparisons here.  Surely you meant to do positional testing -- first with first, second with second, and so on...  That requires only a single loop, not two loops nested.

Comment: If you are allergic to `std::tolower` or `std::toupper`, search the internet for "c++ switch case fall through", which will cut the size of your `switch/case` statement by half.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your code contains multiple errors.

1. `char studentAnswers[] = {};` Here you create an empty array (what obviously makes no sense in your application). Seems like you want it to have 10 elements: `char studentAnswers[10] = {};`.
2. The `grade(...)` function you implemented accepts two `char` as parameters. You cannot use indexing on them. Instead, you want to accept arrays (exactly, pointers to arrays): `grade(char const* correct, char const* student)`.
3. Finally, as paddy suggested, you are calculating the number of correct answers wrongly. Check out their comment.

Glad to hear if I missed something.

Answer (score -2):

The parameters in the function grade need to be declared as an array. Also declare the size of the empty array

```
const char correctAnswers[] = {'B','D', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D'};
char studentAnswers[sizeof correctAnswers] = {};
bool grade(char correctAnswers[], char studentAnswers[]){
    
    for(int b=0; b<correctAnswers.size(); b++){
            for(int j=0; j<studentAnswers.size(); j++){
                if(correctAnswers[b]==studentAnswers[j]){
                    ++ansCorrect;
                }
            }
                
        }

    return ansCorrect >= 8; //8 out of 10 correct
}
```

Comment: Arrays don't have members, you can't call `.size()` on them. You also pass the arrays by pointer to the first value, so you can't deduce their size locally. You need to look at the size of the global objects, which would defeat the purpose of passing them as arguments in the first place.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Only lunatics shy away from std::vector.